# Using Set-SenderFilterConfig to Add rather than Replace

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server

I'm trying to use PowerShell remotely through a c# console app to add domains and senders to the blocked list.

I'm trying to use the syntax from https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996920(v=exchg.160).aspx to just add rather than replace the collection (which I've already done, fun times) but I can't seem to get it right.

The value of the `parameter` is coming out correct as per the syntax @{Add="spam@gmail.co.uk"} but I'm getting the error:

```
Cannot convert value "@{Add="spam@gmail.co.uk"}" to type "Microsoft.Exchange.Data.MultiValuedProperty`1[Microsoft.Exchange.Data.SmtpAddress]". 
Error: "Failed to convert @{Add="spam@gmail.co.uk"} from System.String to Microsoft.Exchange.Data.SmtpAddress. 
Error: Error while converting string '@{Add="spam@gmail.co.uk"}' to result type Microsoft.Exchange.Data.SmtpAddress: "@{Add="spam@gmail.co.uk"}" is not a valid SMTP address"
```

It's pretty obvious that this, as it is, isn't a valid SMTP address but
Is there some flag I'm missing that forces the 'Add' to work?

```
if (acceptedDomains.Contains(item.Subject.Split('@').Last()))
{
    var parameter = new CommandParameter("BlockedSenders", @"@{Add=""" + item.Subject + @"""}");
    command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
}
else
{
    var parameter = new CommandParameter("BlockedDomainsAndSubdomains", @"@{Add=""" + item.Subject.Split('@').Last() + @"""}");
    command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
}
pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
pipeline.Commands.Add(command);
results = pipeline.Invoke();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@{Add="spam@gmail.co.uk"}` is valid PowerShell syntax for creating a `Hashtable`, but you are constructing the parameter in C#. As a result, the command will be passed the *string* `@{Add="spam@gmail.co.uk"}` without further evaluation, which then cannot be converted to what the cmdlet accepts. Instead, try

```
var parameter = new CommandParameter(
    "BlockedSenders", 
    new Hashtable { { "Add", item.Subject } }
);
```

For multiple senders, pass an array:

```
var parameter = new CommandParameter(
    "BlockedSenders", 
    new Hashtable { { "Add", new[] { item1.Subject, item2.Subject } } }
);
```

(Though, given PowerShell's flexibility in this, anything that implements `IEnumerable` should do.)

Comment: It works! Thank you. I really wish there was more documentation on this. Would adding multiple just be `new Hashtable { {"Add", item.Subject}, {"Add", item2.Subject}}` Or `{"Add", item.Subject, item2.Subject}`?